# Appending URL parameters to txt file PHP

Tags: php

I need to store data of visitors to my url but its not inserting into my txt file.

First Q: how do i define the correct fopen path?
2nd Q: why is it not appending?

and yes i've seen this but is "home" my root directory of my ftp or url?

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.txt", "r");
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.gif", "wb");
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
$handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w");
```

here is url with all possible parameters where xxx  can be changed

http://financewizard.info/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.php?email=xxx&offer=xxx&day=xxx&subject=xxx&source=xxx&content=xxx

here is txt file

http://financewizard.info/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.txt

```
<?php
    //?email=xxx&offer=xxx&day=xxx&subject=xxx&source=xxx&content=xxx
    //sample url   financewizard.info/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.php?email=xxx&offer=xxx&day=xxx&subject=xxx&source=xxx&content=xxx
  $email = $_GET['email'];
  $offer = $_GET['offer'];
  $day = $_GET['day'];
  $subject = $_GET['subject'];
  $source = $_GET['source'];
  $content = $_GET['content'];

  $data .= "$email,$offer,$day,$subject,$source,$content"; // Email value.

  echo $data;
  
  $data .= "\n"; // Add a new line.
    
  `// Write the email address to file.
  //
  $file = fopen("/home/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.txt","a+");

  fwrite($file, $data);

  // Redirect the user to advertisers unsubscribe page.

  header("Location: https://www.google.com/");

?>
```

Comment: Does `/home/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.txt` exist, and what permissions are set on the file?

Comment: yes it does i provided the link above. i dont know how to set permission. i just uploaded it in file zilla.i will look

Comment: i found permissions were read and  write. i added execute to the mix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)** instead.  And **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** will give you your home path:

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get path of current php file and set other part of path. obviously the path is not `/home/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.txt`

```
var_dump(dirname(__FILE__)); //to see what the path of current php file
$filePath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../myfile.txt'; //set it how your file tree is generated
$file = fopen($filePath,"a+");
```

Comment: would i just add thts code anywhere in the php file correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be a mixture of file permissions and path.

my code worked fine

thanks

Comment: Kindly explain exactly what the problem was for this Answer to be useful to others.

Comment: my path was wrong for the unsubscribe.txt file and i had to enable ALL permissions (777)

Comment: ```$file = fopen('/kunden/homepages/31/d784186148/htdocs/unsubscribers/unsubscribe.txt',"a+");```

Comment: I do not want to put my path

Comment: I just search the internet how to find file absolute path 1&1 ionos my hosting provider and replace

Comment: And 4/5 of permissions I right clicked on the file in filezilla and checked all permission boxes

Comment: If your code was fine you should not mark another answer accepted. You should instead delete the question.